# How do I see what features are installed on a Windows Server? Where-Object does not return any results

Tags: windows-server-2016, powershell-5.0

I'm getting started with Windows Server 2016, and I'm using a CLI-only version. I'm trying to determine what features are installed on my computer. I tried to do so by viewing stuff with

```
Get-WindowsFeature
```

Obviously I don't like reading everything manually to see whether or not it's installed. So I would like to only list the things that are actually installed.

I tried to do so with the following command:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_."install state" -like "Installed"}
```

This returns nothing at all (Note that when I view everything there are modules installed). And when I try to run the commando below, I actually get content returned:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_."name" -like "dns"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a wrong usage of the `Where-Object` command? Is the underlying name for "install state" something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm trying to determine what features are installed on my Computer.

Use the following PowerShell command:

> This PowerShell one-liner will import the ServerManager module and show Windows roles and features that are currently installed.
>
> ```
> Import-module servermanager ; Get-WindowsFeature | where-object {$_.Installed -eq $True} | format-list DisplayName
> ```
>
> To just return True or False if a specific role or feature is installed, you can use this (which uses the Hyper-V role as an example):
>
> ```
> Import-module servermanager ; (Get-WindowsFeature -name hyper-v).Installed
> ```
>
> For more information, see:
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732757.aspx

Source [Show Installed Windows Roles and Features](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2592d8e7-f830-4d64-bce8-fb4f79ddc66c)

Comment: tl;dr: It works, but has downsides
full story: It returns the correct data, but it only shows the displayname, and thus the hierarchy isn't visible anymore. The answer below is better. But still, it works, so thanks!

Comment: @sniker824 Try removing `| format-list DisplayName` from the command

Answer (score 1):

Sending the command's output through `Format-Custom` always helps you determine the property names you are looking for.

In this case:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.InstallState -like "Installed"}
```

...will solve your problem.

Comment: This works. So appearently it was the name that was different in the underlying code. Thanks a lot, Also nice that it keeps the original formatting

Comment: Indeed, this was the issue for me (using `-like` worked where `-eq` did not). I had a bunch of Microsoft Teams users and was trying to find ones that had a custom policy applied. Despite seeing many in my full list when I just called `$Users`, I got no results when I tried `$Users | Where-Object TeamsPolicy -eq 'CustomPolicyName'`